# PHP: sort folder first and then files

Tags: php, sorting, directory

```
$dir = '/master/files';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
   if(($file != '.') && ($file != '..')){
      if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){
         echo '<li class="folder">'.$file.'</li>';
      }else{
         echo '<li class="file">'.$file.'</li>';
      }
   }
}
```

From the script above, I get result:

```
images (folder)
index.html    
javascript (folder)
style.css
```

How to sort the folder first and then files?

Comment: first save them in two array and then print them (folder first and then files) :)

Comment: You mean I have to make two "foreach"? One for folder and then for files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
$dir = '/master/files';
$directories = array();
$files_list  = array();
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
   if(($file != '.') && ($file != '..')){
      if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){
         $directories[]  = $file;

      }else{
         $files_list[]    = $file;

      }
   }
}

foreach($directories as $directory){
   echo '<li class="folder">'.$directory.'</li>';
}
foreach($files_list as $file_list){
   echo '<li class="file">'.$file_list.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: I think two foreach is not good, save li when creating the array, then using implode for printing is better

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to make 2 loops, you can do the job with this piece of code:

```
<?php

function scandirSorted($path) {

    $sortedData = array();
    foreach(scandir($path) as $file) {

        // Skip the . and .. folder
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..')
            continue;            

        if(is_file($path . $file)) {
            // Add entry at the end of the array
            array_push($sortedData, '<li class="folder">' . $file . '</li>');
        } else {
            // Add entry at the begin of the array
            array_unshift($sortedData, '<li class="file">' . $file . '</li>');
        }
    }
    return $sortedData;
}

?>
```

This function will return the list of entries of your path, folders first, then files.

Comment: styling in loop is good idea, but this will not sort folders or files `a-z` order.

Comment: Indeed, if the order is important, then you have to use 2 arrays

Answer (score 3):

Modifying your code as little as possible:

```
$folder_list = "";
$file_list = "";
$dir = '/master/files';
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
   if(($file != '.') && ($file != '..')){
      if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){
         $folder_list .= '<li class="folder">'.$file.'</li>';
      }else{
         $file_list .= '<li class="file">'.$file.'</li>';
      }
   }
}

print $folder_list;
print $file_list;
```

This only loops through everything once, rather than requiring multiple passes.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for N deep recursive directory scan:

```
function scanRecursively($dir = "/") {
    $scan = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));
    $tree = array();
    $queue = array();
    foreach ( $scan as $item ) 
        if ( is_file($item) ) $queue[] = $item;
        else $tree[] = scanRecursively($dir . '/' . $item);
    return array_merge($tree, $queue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the output in 2 arrays, then iterate through the arrays to output them in the right order.

```
$dir = '/master/files';

$contents = scandir($dir);

// create blank arrays to store folders and files
$folders = $files = array();

foreach ($contents as $file) {

    if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {

        if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {

            // add to folders array
            $folders[] = $file;

        } else {

            // add to files array
            $files[] = $file;

        }
    }
}

// output folders
foreach ($folders as $folder) {

    echo '<li class="folder">' . $folder . '</li>';

}

// output files
foreach ($files as $file) {

    echo '<li class="file">' . $file . '</li>';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    chdir ($path);

    $dir = array_diff (scandir ('.'), array ('.', '..', '.DS_Store', 'Thumbs.db'));

    usort ($dir, create_function ('$a,$b', '
        return  is_dir ($a)
        ? (is_dir ($b) ? strnatcasecmp ($a, $b) : -1)
        : (is_dir ($b) ? 1 : (
            strcasecmp (pathinfo ($a, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), pathinfo ($b, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 0
            ? strnatcasecmp ($a, $b)
            : strcasecmp (pathinfo ($a, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), pathinfo ($b, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
        ))
    ;
'));

    header ('content-type: text/plain');
    print_r ($dir);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Being a CodeIgniter lover, I have in fact modified the core **directory_helper** from that to include the ability to have certain files exempt from the scanning in addition to setting the depth and choosing if hidden files should be included.

> All credit goes to the original authors of CI. I simply added to it
>   with the exempt array and building in the sorting.

It uses ksort to order the folders, as the folder name is set as the key and natsort to order the files inside each folder.

The only thing you may need to do is define what the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is for your environment but I don't think you will need to modify much else.

```
function directory_map($source_dir, $directory_depth = 0, $hidden = FALSE, $exempt = array())
{
    if ($fp = @opendir($source_dir))
    {
        $folddata   = array();
        $filedata   = array();
        $new_depth  = $directory_depth - 1;
        $source_dir = rtrim($source_dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

        while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($fp)))
        {
            // Remove '.', '..', and hidden files [optional]
            if ($file === '.' OR $file === '..' OR ($hidden === FALSE && $file[0] === '.'))
            {
                continue;
            }

            is_dir($source_dir.$file) && $file .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

            if (($directory_depth < 1 OR $new_depth > 0) && is_dir($source_dir.$file))
            {
                $folddata[$file] = directory_map($source_dir.$file, $new_depth, $hidden, $exempt);

            }
            elseif(empty($exempt) || !empty($exempt) && !in_array($file, $exempt))
            {
                $filedata[] = $file;
            }
        }

        !empty($folddata) ? ksort($folddata) : false;
        !empty($filedata) ? natsort($filedata) : false;

        closedir($fp);
        return array_merge($folddata, $filedata);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Usage example would be:

```
$filelist = directory_map('full_server_path');
```

As mentioned above, it will set the folder name as the key for the child array, so you can expect something along the lines of the following:

```
Array(
[documents/] => Array(
    [0] => 'document_a.pdf',
    [1] => 'document_b.pdf'    
    ),
[images/] => Array(
    [tn/] = Array(
        [0] => 'picture_a.jpg',
        [1] => 'picture_b.jpg'
        ),
    [0] => 'picture_a.jpg',
    [1] => 'picture_b.jpg'        
    ),
[0] => 'file_a.jpg',
[1] => 'file_b.jpg'
);
```

Just keep in mind that the exempt will be applied to all folders. This is handy if you want to skip out a index.html file or other file that is used in the directories you don't want included.

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function sortedScanDir($dir) {
  // scan the current folder
  $content = scandir($dir);

  // create arrays
  $folders = [];
  $files = [];

  // loop through
  foreach ($content as $file) {
    $fileName = $dir . '/' . $file;
    if (is_dir($fileName)) {
      $folders[] = $file;
    } else {
      $files[] = $file;
    }
  }

  // combine
  return array_merge($folders, $files);
}
```